# Convert HTML string into Jquery Object

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML string which is a mix of text plus HTML tags, which i'm trying to convert into an object. So for e.g. my HTML string would look like:

```
Pay using your <img src="visa-src" /> or your <img src="mc-src" />
```

I'm using jquery 1.8.0 and tried using `$(HTMLSTRING)` however for some reason it strips out the text before the anchor and gives the rest, i.e. object with the children `#img, #text` and `#img` while the first text (Pay using your) gets stripped off

However lets say if the input is:

```
<img src="visa-src" /> or your <img src="mc-src" />
```

it correctly gives me the object with three child elements in it #img, #text and #img.

Are there any other ways to convert this properly?

Update:
What i'm ultimately looking at is to change the each of the img src there in the HTML string and prepend with some host there.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any `a` tag in your code

Comment: Works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2A3Uf/

Comment: @user1671639, i've updated my question with the img reference.

Comment: @RGraham, that basically renders that into the DOM which is something im not looking for. I should have been more explicit. I've updated the question.

Comment: Probably too late to be of use, but can you not just wrap HTMLSTRING in a `<p>` before you make it a jQuery object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

```
$.parseHTML()
```

instead of

```
$(HTMLSTRING)
```

See below JS Code..

```
var HTMLSTRING = 'Pay using your <img src="visa-src" /> or your <img src="mc-src" />';

var HTMLSTRING1 = '<img src="visa-src" /> or your <img src="mc-src" />';

console.log($.parseHTML(HTMLSTRING));
console.log($.parseHTML(HTMLSTRING1));
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYcaJ/)

Comment: Nikhil, which version of jQuery has the parseHTML. I can only see the parseJSON and parseXML API's as part of my jQuery.

Comment: ok looks like i don't get have the parseHTML as part of my jQuery (1.8.0-min.js). Any other ways to go about this?

Comment: I can see parseHTML function in 1.8.0 source..http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js

Comment: Hi, it's maybe a silly question, but how to get html string back ?

Answer (score 33):

`$.parseHTML()` parses a string into an **array of DOM nodes**.

To create the **object** you need to add `$()`:

```
$($.parseHTML(yourString))
```

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j05ucnfv/

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/